# How to loglog plot of a frequency distribution on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph that should look like: [image: loglog plot]. I have a text file with a column called 'dia' which has diameters of craters. My code produces the output as: [image: my output]. I need to plot the crater size frequency distribution against crater diameters. My idea was to group same diameters together and plot these groups but obviously it does not work. Here is my code:

```
y_train = pd.read_csv('diameter.txt',sep='\t', 
index_col=None)
df = y_train['dia'].value_counts()
df.to_csv('dia.txt')
df = pd.read_csv('dia.txt',sep=',', index_col=None, header=None)
plt.loglog(df[0], df[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(data=df, y="cumulative frequency", x="Diameter")
```

or one of the seaborn APIs that helps plotting categories?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it plots a one big fat box :/

Comment: This may be because your Diameter variable is continuous, so maybe use pd.cut to create diameter bins and then use the bins as x categories in your boxplot?